# Unset an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have a problem like i have a multidimensional array and i want to remove a parent array if an inner array contains 'edit'
the array is like this

```
[fields] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [header] => Array
                    (
                        [fieldName] => edit
                        [displayName] => Edit
                        [width] => 40
                        [group] => 0,1,2,3
                        [cssClass] => dgAssetsCentered
                    )

                [visibility] => Array
                    (
                        [showOnStart] => 1
                        [editable] => 
                    )

                [cell] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => link
                        [params] => Array
                            (
                                [label] => Edit
                            )

                    )

                [sort] => Array
                    (
                        [sortable] => 1
                    )

                [validator] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 
                        [params] => 
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [header] => Array
                    (
                        [fieldName] => OFFERID
                        [displayName] => Offer Id
                        [group] => 0
```

i want to remove array 0 because inner array contains 'edit' i am able to delete [header] array not able to delete [0] array.please suggest.

thanks
alex.

Comment: Can you post the code that deletes the header array?

Comment: `unset($array["fields"][0]);` *should* work?

Comment: no it's not working, and it's hardcoded one too sometimes edit may be in another position

Comment: also, you can try array_search()

Comment: the "Edit" can exist in any-key? or only in that "displayName" ? why you dont just unset the field right away instead of filling it with "Edit" and there search for it..

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($fields as $key => $field)
{
  if(isset($field['header']['fieldName']) && $field['header']['fieldName'] == 'edit')
    unset($field[$key]);
}
```

UPD:
Also, if you wanna remove array, if any element equal 'edit', try this algorithm:

```
foreach($fields AS $key => $array)
{
  foreach($array as $innered)
  {
    if(array_search('edit', $innered)) 
    {
      unset($fields[$key]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The above is for 2 dimensional we should call recursively

Answer (score 1):

`unset(fields);` will clear the entire array.

`unset(fields[0]);` will clear the element 0 inside fields array

Comment: This works very well :)
It will unset any variable passed in. Look at usage in my answer.